# Как с помощью js экранировать строку с его абзацами

Tags: javascript, html, json

Допустим у нас есть объект: (в базе)

```
{
  completed: false,
  title: "Test-app",
  text: "Тестовое приложение для проверки работоспособности,
  для оценки дизайна,
  для поиска багов."
}
```

Объект **text** написан с переходами строк

Если мы будем экранировать объект **text**, вывод будет в одну строку -
**"Тестовое приложение для проверки работоспособности, для оценки дизайна, для поиска багов."**

Можно ли выводить так как она написана, с переходами строк?
Например, поставить после каждого абзаца в конце тег `<br>` или обернуть в тег `<p>`

Вот как создал пользователь:
[image: Создать новую заметку]

Вот так она хранится в базе данных:

[image: База данных]

Вот так она отображается на странице:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мне нужно что бы текст с абзацами отображался в три строки а не в одну.
Этот текст я не создаю в коде.

Comment: так сделайте замену `\n` на `<br/>`. в пхп вот для этих целей даже функция `nl2br` есть

Comment: зы: не ясно что в вашем понимании есть экранирование

Comment: Эти данные получаем из базы данных, это текст введённый пользователем, который напечатал текст с абзацами.

Comment: и что это меняет?

Comment: используйте ` `  вместо " " и между ними текст.

Comment: Кажется вы меня не правильно понимаете я сейчас изменю свой вопрос

Comment: вы нам расскажите, как этот текст выводите на страницу. исходя из  этого и решения принимать надо. то как он хранится было понятно еще и первой редакции

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если пользователем текст вводился через textarea, там должны сохранится символы переноса.
Вы можете применить split по раделителю '\n', получить массив строк, и выводить их как хочется.

```js
function splitIt(){
  let ta_str = document.querySelector('.ta').value
  let arr = ta_str.split("\n")
  console.log(arr)
}
```

```html
<textarea class='ta' name="" id="" cols="20" rows="5"></textarea>
<button onclick='splitIt()'>ОК</button>
```

Comment: Благодарю! Это то что мне нужно было.